# How to avoid queueEvent at GLSurfaceView in the case of the same thread

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I am writing the program which processes Android OpenGL at other thread. But it freezes in case of this code. For example, it processes a method directly without calling task.get(), if it's the same thread. Does such a way exist?

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig arg1)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            FutureTask<Object> task = new FutureTask<Object>(new Callable<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object call() {
                    return null;
                }
            });
            gv.queueEvent(task);
            try{
                task.get();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
            Log.i("MainActivity", "Done");    // <- Work
        }
    });
    t.start();

    FutureTask<Object> task = new FutureTask<Object>(new Callable<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call() {
            return null;
        }
    });
    gv.queueEvent(task);
    try{ task.get(); }catch(Exception e){}    // <- Freeze
    Log.i("MainActivity", "Done");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question correctly, there is some code you would like to run in the OpenGL thread **without** using a `FutureTask`, `Runnable` or other asynchronous solution.

First of all, does this code (and any of its data) depend on other threads? Does it need to be synchronized with other code/data? If yes, then you should use `queueEvent()` from a different thread. Since you want to stay within the OpenGL thread completely, I assume that your code to be executed does not have any relationship with other (non-GL) threads.

Moreover, never call `FutureTask.get()` from the same thread as the one which is supposed to perform the `FutureTask` code -- who will perform the job if your thread is waiting for itself? And if you want to send code to the GL thread from another thread, don't use `FutureTask`; just use the simple `Runnable` for it (as an argument to `queueEvent()`).

Back to the main question: to run something from the GL thread without `queueEvent()`, you should decide how exactly you want to perform that job, i.e. when (where) exactly it should be called. Do you want to get it called each time `onDrawFrame()` is called? Or each time `onSurfaceChanged()` or `onSurfaceCreated()` is called?

Since you used `queueEvent()`, I assume you want your code to run before the next upcoming `onDrawFrame()` call. In the Android GL thread, internally, the order of calls is as follows:

1. Android processes all your queued events (I simplified this a bit, but the main point is OK)
2. If needed, Android calls `onSurfaceCreated()`
3. If needed, Android calls `onSurfaceChanged()`
4. Android calls `onDrawFrame()`

So, to put it simple, the code you add with `queueEvent()` will get executed before the next render cycle (`onDrawFrame()`). If you want to run this code on the GL thread in `onDrawFrame()`, you can add it to the beginning of `onDrawFrame()`, for example:

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    if (mDoJob) {
        mDoJob = false;

        // perform code
    }

    ...
}
```

Here, `mDoJob` is a `volatile` variable. You can set it to `true` from another thread. **However, please be warned** that this assumes you don't need any additional synchronization with the other thread that uses the `mDoJob` signal, i.e. all the code that will run in the `mDoJob` condition block will be fine without any further synchronization with anything else.

Basically, what I presented above is just a simplified (non-synchronized) solution to replace `queueEvent()`, which assumes you don't need synchronization (including up-to-date variables as well) with other threads.

If you don't need any signalling (any dependence with other threads), and the value of `mDoJob` can be decided inside the OpenGL thread (inside `onDrawFrame()`, `onSurfaceCreated()` or `onSurfaceChanged()`), then `mDoJob` does not need to be volatile. In such a case, you're staying inside the OpenGL thread, so there is no need for an asynchronous (and thus synchronized) solution.

To sum up, specifically, if you want to decide in `onSurfaceCreated()` whether a code should run in `onDrawFrame()`, just use a (non-volatile) boolean variable, which you set in `onSurfaceCreated()`, and then check it in `onDrawFrame()` (as in my code example above).